# what is the Maximum number of put operation allowed in partitioned azure service bus Queue?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, amqp, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a use case where I need to send very large number of messages to Azure Service Bus queue. From this https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted.md I got to know that the Azure Service Bus queue supports 2000 put operations per second (1kb message).

But my writes will be more than 2000 per second.

From the Microsoft's docs

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-partitions#:~:text=Service%20Bus%20partitions%20enable%20queues,message%20broker%20or%20messaging%20store.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-partitions#:%7E:text=Service%20Bus%20partitions%20enable%20queues,message%20broker%20or%20messaging%20store.)

I have seen that we can create a partitioned queue which will create 16 partitions and the size of queue will be increased by 16 times. But I am not able to find will this have any impact on the put operations? **will the put operations also be increased by 16 times resulting in 32000 writes per second?**

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a very outdated document, current limits for standard SKU is 1000 credits per second (per namespace), take a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling#what-are-the-credit-limits) for more info on how credits works.

Regarding your question, what partitioned entities do is dividing your entitiy into multiple logical components in order to achieve higher resiliency, when you send a message to a partitioned entitiy there will be an internal load balancing mechanism that distribute messages across all partitions, this is not counted as additional operations, hence if you send 1000 messages per second that is equivalent to 1000 credits.

Comment: So how can i send more than 1000 messages per second in Azure Service Bus Queue?

Comment: You should consider the premium sku which will give you isolated resources for your namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging, with this sku there is no limit of messages per second but rather the limits will come based on cpu/memory/storage io utilization